# session()->flush() borra los {!! csrf_field(); !!}

Tags: php, laravel

Cuando hago una desconexión mando a la función : 
Con el objetivo de borrar todas las sessiones que ese usuario ha ido creando.

```
 public function Desconectarse(Request $request) {

         session()->flush();

         return view('index');
     }
```

Y cuando en el index pongo usuario y contraseña da error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

Answer (score 0):

El token de csrf se guarda en sesión por lo que se destruye al utilizar flush y por tanto deja de estar disponible en esa petición.

En tu caso veo que se pretende desconectar, en este caso deberías aplicar una redirección  en lugar de retornar la vista, así de esta manera se regenerar el token.

Es decir:

```
public function Desconectarse(Request $request) {

     session()->flush();
     // redireccion a la ruta deseada
     return redirect('user/login');
    // o utiliza el alias de la ruta 
    return redirect()->route('login');
 }
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo del redirect,  he puesto      session()->regenerate();
     y nada

Comment: Simplemente en lugar de mostrar directamente la vista redirecciona a la ruta del login. Puedes usar también **return redirect()->route('login');** donde login es el alias de la ruta.

Comment: Pero da igual redirect que return view, el problema es que los csr han sido eliminados.... o influye el redirect para que no se eliminen ??

Comment: No es lo mismo, no es lo mismo mostrar X página que decirle al navegador que estas en X (logout) y vaya a Z (login), esto hará una petición nueva y regenera las sesiones. Por otro lado no tiene sentido mostrar la vista de login en la ruta de logout es una inconsistencia semántica